# CouchDB _changes, view related

Tags: couchdb

Simple question: I would like to react to some changes in a database, but only to those changes which are causing modifications in a certain `view1`. That is, I am not interested in all changes in the database, just those changes which are affecting `view1`. I am not talking about filter here, just about view+changes. Something like this (although this is probably not correct):

```
http://localhost:5984/db/_design/doc1/_view/view1/_changes
```

Is this at all supported by CouchDB? Does this makes sense at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible, but in a little another way. Since 1.1.0 release CouchDB is able to [use map function as filters](https://github.com/apache/couchdb/commit/56086f07c425bd272bda5a6609ed9db3758178ba) for changes feed. This works as like regular filters: if key-value pair was emitted at least once for changed document it means that he passes filter and `_changes` yields the record about him. If you need get only new updates for specific view, you need to specify staring `since` seq number - it could be easily retrieved from `_design/ddoc-name/_info` resource from field `view_index/update_seq`. Since 1.3 release you may also specify `since=now` to listen updates from current point of time.

Note, that this view filters doesn't uses view index and doesn't updates him while new changes occurs. Also, there is [set of patches](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COUCHDB-1398) that improves view filters in the way that you may be also interested.